# How to fix setState hook being ignored within ReactSwing Api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, react-functional-component

I am setting up a tinder like swipe funtion within my react application using a library called ReactSwing(https://github.com/ssanjun/react-swing), I have been working from the functional component example https://github.com/ssanjun/react-swing/blob/master/Examples/index-hook.js. The Api is running and swipe function looks great but adding and removing cards from the deck is proving difficult due to the fact I can't access the stacks functions. the example states the I use set state like this

```
 const [stack, setStack] = useState(null);

      //logging cards thrown
     const cardThrown = (targetCard) => {
       //logs stack
        console.log(stack);
      };

        <ReactSwing
                  className="stack"
                  setStack={(stack) => setStack(stack)}
                  throwout={cardThrown}
                >
```

The log for this appears as null even though I know it should work because `setStack={(stack) => console.log(stack)}` presents me with

```
{getConfig: ƒ, getSpringSystem: ƒ, on: ƒ, createCard: ƒ, getCard: ƒ, …}
childElements: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
createCard: ƒ (element, prepend)
destroyCard: ƒ (card)
getCard: ƒ (element)
getConfig: ƒ ()
getSpringSystem: ƒ ()
on: ƒ (eventName, listener)
__proto__: Object
```

I have also set up a sandbox(https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-sunset-jqjst?file=/src/App.js) to potentially help further really struggling with this one, thanks in advance.

Update: Using the react component tool in chrome I can see that the state has infact been updated but I can't access it using following the suggested methods in the API documentation or console log it, and I can't work out why?

Update 2: using

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(stack)
      }, [stack]);
```

shows me that it has updated the usestate but a regular console log upon swipe is still null?

Comment: you should probably call the setstack on some  change function which might be available in ReactSwing lib

Comment: unfortunately, all change functions offered by the library are swipe events and the stack would have to be defined prior to a swipe event to trigger some of the events such as destroy cards. according to the documentation, this is the correct way to do it setStack is a ReactSwing function and as you can see in the image I uploaded it does update state I just can't access it.